# Is the thirty something year old RJ45 jack as small as it will ever get?

Tags: hardware, network, laptop, ethernet

Why are micro-ethernet adapters not a thing?  A physical adapter that takes our thirty year old standard sized RJ45 jack on one side and and plugs into a TabletPC on the other.

Every other form of high speed communications has already shrunk to much smaller than the RJ45 form factor.   All of the following can achieve speeds much faster than 1Gbps but have much smaller sized physical connections:

1. miniUSB
2. microUSB
3. USB-C
4. displayPort
5. microDisplayPort
6. miniHDMI
7. microHDMI
8. miniSAS - SCSI Attached Storage

So how were these other technologies able to shrink  to small connector size but at faster speeds?   Yes, ethernet works over distances of 100meters whereas none of the above except miniSAS work directly over 5meters, but of course MiniSAS is much much faster. Certainly engineering and modern manufacturing could make a physical adapter to reduce the physical size down to easily fit in a modern laptop, not cause NEXT and still not slow the speed down that much? The conductors have to be closer together, so microRJ45 would need to mitigate Near End CrossTalk or NEXT. Could that be achieved at manufacturing by increasing the twists-per-inch inside the adapter?

Please do not answer with Ethernet-to-USB dongles as they are insecure, severely limited for PXE, have driver issues, and unstable.

Thirty years from now, will the RJ45 ethernet jack on PCs be antiquated?   Will we chatting about the old days of RJ45 wired ethernet like we talk about token-ring and dot matrix printers today?

I have asked this same question in electronics, physics and Network Engineering, but it was rejected in every single one.  They suggested to ask in retro computing.

Comment: Retro computing talks about the past not predicts the future...

Comment: Perhaps a miniaturized AAUI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Attachment_Unit_Interface)?

Comment: "Why didn't"  questions are already a bad fir for RC.SE, more so speculation about recent and future developments as all of them are calling for opinions. If taken technical, it's about actual technology, not history or retro developments. So I'd say EE.SE as well as Networking is a good fit. If they don't see it, then maybe some futurist forum?

Comment: For the cases where size matters, the future is obviously multiplex everything into usb type c thunderbolt. For the cases where size doesn't matter, well it doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, most of the question is historical.  All these other technologies miniaturized very quickly.  How were they able to miniaturize at faster speeds but not ethernet?

Comment: @user3528438  That does not answer the question.  The insecurity of USB-C alone is a reason that is not answer in many cases.

Comment: @rjt many cases where size matters or not?

Comment: I don't think the size of the RJ45 connector has anything to do with Ethernet speed.  the 1Gbps limit comes from the capacitance of up to 100 meters of twisted pair wiring, increasing speed requires lowering the capacitance, which is easiest to do by shortening cable lengths to a few feet or less.  I'm not an EE but I believe the capacitance contribution of the RJ45 connector is negligible.

Comment: To make this just a little retrocomputing-relevant: There *were* small form factor Ethernet connectors for PCMCIA Ethernet cards (think mid-to-late 90s). They connected the card to an external dongle, which in turn housed the BNC and/or RJ45 connector (and maybe some physical layer stuff).

Comment: I think the answer to the "why not" question is that there was no need, as Wifi provides an adequate replacement for small devices, and large devices have no problem with RJ45.

Comment: "Thirty years from now..." - I will probably be dead, and won't care!

Comment: Since this *is* retrocomputing: RJ45?  Call *that* an ethernet connector? [*This*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_tap) is an Ethernet connector!

Comment: @rjt mind to explain what historical fact you're asking for? The only one I can see is that no miniaturization ever happened - which you already state, so what other historical part there is?

Comment: I'd assume that "micro RJ45" as you call it (Micro-[Modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector) would be a more correct name) never happened because it's the wire the connector attaches to that determined the size in the first place, and replacing all that installed wire or mixing two different kinds of connectors in patch panels just isn't worth avoiding having a little passive adapter hanging off your PCMCIA cards.

Comment: Micro-HDMI can carry ethernet.  My bet would be USB-C though.

Comment: @another-dave, I held one in my hand and it does have a certain reassuring weight to .  This one was used with a DEC-20. https://twitter.com/larsbrinkhoff/status/1124751897678745600

Comment: Considering the size of the wiring and the mechanical needs for a cable strain relief and good retention strength, it's a pretty compact little connector. Question is, how much smaller could a new smaller one be? If you're saving 10%, there's no return on the investment needed to introduce and implement the replacement and suffer the industry disruption.

Comment: I knew ethernet used to be huge, but did not know that big.  It is amazing one can hold a bag of 50 RJ45 male ends and not even feel the weight.  RJ45 ethernet connectors are a remarkable achievement.  I cannot imagine a field tech installing a smaller network adapter.  This would just be at the laptop end where there would be the normal sized ethernet patch cable plugged-in to a micro ethernet adapter.

Comment: @rjt  normally that MAU would be connected to a multi-port transceiver like the Digital (DEC) DELNI. Still that H4000 (IEEE 802.3) did 10 Mbit compared with the XEROX Ethernet design's 3 Mbit.  And oh yes it worked well enough on distances up to 2.5 km (5 cable segments.)  I don't think an HDMI cable 500 m long would work that well.......

Comment: What has happened is this : Moore's axiom has kicked in - the speed's which todays Ethernet (1 Gbit) provide on copper is dependent on fast processors (the algorithm doing the signal processing requires a lot of math.)